# Codeigniter Session matching IP

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

i was wondering which could be the main problems related to using the session_matching the user IP?

Has i understand this will make the session table little smaller cause if ip is found the session is regenerated from the same db field, or i'm mistaking?

My dubt is that having many users on site, this will produce many many session table fields without ip matching parameter setted to TRUE, cause, if session does not match user ip a new db field is used for the user session, is this true?

This is an example to show what i think i learned about session db table:

```
$config['session_match_ip'] = false;

3000000 users on site = 3000000 session db records.
3000000 users returns on site = 6000000 session db records. (cause everytime user is a NEW USER)

$config['session_match_ip'] = true;

3000000 users on site = 3000000 session db records.
3000000 users returns on site = 4500000 session db records. (cause ,maybe, 1500 users uses static IP)
```

is this logic right?

thanks.

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: no problems, i would like to know if sess match user ip will produce a smaller db session table

Comment: If performance is what you are refering to, then 6000 records is nothing. I don't know how codeigniter session table works but, there must be a garbage collector. Even if it isn't present, then you can use a cron job. This is just how it should be. Will dive into codeigniter session class now and lets see what it gives.

Comment: I'm pretty sure codeigniter does garbage collection on older session data.

Comment: @Jeemusu if is there way to find out if it does will be great man!

Comment: Check the [codeigniter documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) : `"Note: The Session class has built-in garbage collection which clears out expired sessions so you do not need to write your own routine to do it."`

Comment: you can answering to the question and i'll flag it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally, you will have more records in your database if you chose to use `$config['session_match_ip']` set to `false` . However, if you check the [codeigniter documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html), you will see that codeigniter does garbage collection on expired sessions, which should keep things under control for you.

> "Note: The Session class has built-in garbage collection which clears
>   out expired sessions so you do not need to write your own routine to
>   do it."

Answer (score 0):

[i see another link here that may help you about session matching = ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977284/safe-authentication-in-codeigniter)

this one may be differ but much more usefull that creating a db field for sessions into your db

Comment: ok, but sorry is not related to what i'm asking for!